# SQL query to SUM and COUNT

Tags: sql

I am using a query to get some results that I want to make my application works, but I've made some tests and I found that some results aren't correct. I am using the database from Microsoft Visual Studio. This is the query that I am actually running

```
SELECT Filetype AS 'Extensão', 
    COUNT(*) AS 'Nº total de extensões',
    ((COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile)) AS 'Percentagem (%)',
    SUM(Filesize) AS 'Total(KB)'
    FROM infofile 
    GROUP BY Filetype
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL,
    COUNT('Nº total de extensões'),
    ((COUNT(Filetype) * 100) / (SELECT COUNT(Filetype) FROM infofile)), 
    SUM(Filesize)
    FROM infofile
```

And I am getting this results

[image]

But if you SUM every row on the Percentagem column it won't give the 100%. You know what I mean?

This is the result that I get after add .0 here 
`((COUNT(Filetype) * 100.0) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM infofile))`
 But I don't want to get the result of the 100% with 100.0000000

Comment: Because a percentage may be 3.2345 in reality and you print out just 3. Of course this does not add up right.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using SQL Server which uses integer division.  That explains the why the results are off.  You can fix that by using decimal points.

Also, you can use `grouping sets` to get the total rather than a union and simplify the calculation by using `AVG()`:

```
SELECT Filetype AS [Extensão], 
       COUNT(*) AS 'Nº total de extensões',
       AVG(FileType * 100.0) AS [Percentagem (%)],
       SUM(Filesize) AS [Total(KB)]
FROM infofile 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (Filetype), () );
```

Comment: I've used my query but instead of run your query I've just changed 100 to 100.0. I think that's ok right?

Comment: I've just realized that I can't use that method because the column that I am trying to get the percentage is nvarchar. So I cant you AVG